# Camel CXF + JAX-WS + SoapHeader

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

How can I parse SOAP headers within apache camel processor from apache camel cxf endpoint in POJO mode:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="MyWS" address="http://localhost:8080/services/MyWS" serviceClass="tmp.MyWS" />

<route>
  <from uri="cxf:bean:MyWS" />
  <process ref="MyProcessor" />
</route>
```

On the official apache camel cxf website I found an example how to set headers, but there is no examples about getting them. How can I get messageId value. My SOAP request looks like that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inv="http://inv.org">
   <soapenv:Header>
    <inv:messageId>111</inv:messageId>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
     ...
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Marcin there is some information at this link: http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html there is a section called How to get and set SOAP headers in POJO mode. Please see this link.

Comment: I've already read it but there is no info about getting headers

Comment: This line of code seems to get the headers. `List<SoapHeader> soapHeaders = CastUtils.cast((List<?>)exchange.getIn().getHeader(Header.HEADER_LIST));` Have you tried it?

Comment: yes, but how to parse SoapHeader to get messageId. This class has only getObject method which returns org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementNSImpl

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276538/elementnsimpl-to-string

Comment: Use interceptors to get the soap message and add the message into the camel exchange as a header and then use xpath to get the value from that header.Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In the Camel Route builder we will get the SOAP Header using simple componenent, in the below example I am apply cbr using SOAP operation name i.e.

from("cxf:bean:xyz-ws?dataFormat=POJO").routeId("xyz-ws").log( "This is ${in.header.operationName} operation called...." )
.log( "Entering inside the Choice with operation....${in.header.operationName}")
.when(simple("${in.header.operationName} == 'getDataFromDictionary'"))

Hope this is helpfull.